# Is it possible to detect and handle string collisions among grouped values when grouping in Hadoop Pig?

Tags: grouping, apache-pig

Assuming I have lines of data like the following that show user names and their favorite fruits:

```
Alice\tApple
Bob\tApple
Charlie\tGuava
Alice\tOrange
```

I'd like to create a pig query that shows the favorite fruit of each user. If a user appears multiple times, then I'd like to show "Multiple". For example, the result with the data above should be:

```
Alice\tMultiple
Bob\tApple
Charlie\tGuava
```

In SQL, this could be done something like this (although it wouldn't necessarily perform very well):

```
select user, case when count(fruit) > 1 then 'Multiple' else max(fruit) end
from FruitPreferences
group by user
```

But I can't figure out the equivalent PigLatin. Any ideas?

Comment: I should note that this problem is similar to, but distinct from, another question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406522/is-it-possible-to-cross-join-a-row-in-a-relation-with-a-tuple-in-that-row-in-pig/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a ["Aggregate Function" Pig UDF](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual) (scroll down to "Aggregate Functions"). This is a user-defined function that takes a bag and outputs a scalar. So basically, your UDF would take in the bag, determine if there is more than one item in it, and transform it accordingly with an if statement.

I can think of a way of doing this without a UDF, but it is definitely awkward. After your `GROUP`, use `SPLIT` to split your data set into two: one in which the count is 1 and one in which the count is more than one:

```
SPLIT grouped INTO one IF COUNT(fruit) == 0, more IF COUNT(fruit) > 0;
```

Then, separately use `FOREACH ... GENERATE` on each to transform it:

```
one = FOREACH one GENERATE name, MAX(fruit); -- hack using MAX to get the item
more = FOREACH more GENERATE name, 'Multiple';
```

Finally, union them back:

```
out = UNION one, more;
```

I haven't really found a better way of handing the same data set in two different ways based on some conditional, like you want. I typically do some sort of split/recombine like I did here. I believe Pig will be smart and make a plan that doesn't use more than 1 M/R job.

Disclaimer: I can't actually test this code at the moment, so it may have some mistakes.

---

Update:

In looking harder, I was reminded of the [bicond operator](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/basic.html#arithmetic) and I think that will work here.

```
b = FOREACH a GENERATE name, (COUNT(fruit)==1 ? MAX(FRUIT) : 'Multiple');
```

Comment: Awesome, I wasn't sure if the bicond operator would work for this or not -- I'll try that first. Otherwise I'll fall back on the split/union method you described.